# Need help with integral and change the variable

Tags: definite-integrals

I have

$$\displaystyle \int_0^\pi \sqrt{x} ~\cos x ~dx$$

and I need to make change of the variable $u = \sin x$.

Comment: Why in the world make that change of variables? Let $u=\sqrt x$ instead!

Comment: The teacher want this, he told me first to make change on the limits of the integral -pi/2 0 pi/2 :(

Comment: Well, that would mean $u=\pi/2-x$, but this won't get you anywhere. Perhaps your teacher wants you to think about symmetry, like $\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} x\cos x\,dx$, but that won't help here.

Comment: This will *not* work. You'll end up with two integrals that can be done only by coming back to the original problem and doing it the right way!! Sorry to be a grouch. Sometimes — and I should know — teachers just make mistakes.

Comment: Actually, your integrand doesn't have an elementary antiderivative; are you sure the problem wasn't $\int \sqrt{x} \cos^2 x dx$?

Comment: Yeah, @Zen wins. We get the Fresnel integral, and, although the improper integral $\int_0^\infty \sin(t^2)\,dt$ can be evaluated, this can't. As I said, we teachers make mistakes.

Comment: This is not an elementary integral.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^\pi\sqrt{x}\cos x~dx=\int_0^\pi x^{\frac{1}{2}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}dx=\int_0^\pi\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n+\frac{1}{2}}}{(2n)!}dx=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{2n+\frac{3}{2}}}{(2n)!\left(2n+\dfrac{3}{2}\right)}\right]_0^\pi=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2(-1)^n\pi^{2n+\frac{3}{2}}}{(2n)!(4n+3)}$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try this if you want:
$$x\sqrt { x } =u\\ x={ u }^{ \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  }\\ \sqrt { x } ={ u }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }\\ dx=\frac { 2 }{ 3 } { u }^{ \frac { -1 }{ 3 }  }du\\ \int _{ 0 }^{ \pi  } \sqrt { x } \cos  x~ dx=\int _{ 0 }^{ \pi  }{ u } ^{ \frac { 1 }{ 3 }  }\cos { u } ^{ \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  }\frac { 2 }{ 3 } { u }^{ \frac { -1 }{ 3 }  }du=\frac { 2 }{ 3 } \int _{ 0 }^{ \pi\sqrt\pi  }{ \cos { u } ^{ \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  }du } $$

$\int { \cos { u } ^{ \frac { 2 }{ 3 }  }du } $ does not have an analytical expression. You can try on wolframalpha.com .

Comment: What earthly good is that?!!

Answer (score -1):

Write x as a function of u: you have $u=\sin(x)$ so $x=\arcsin(u)$. It gets a little sticky when you have to simplify $\cos(\arcsin(u))$; remember the identity $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$, letting $\theta=\arcsin u$ (arcsin gives you an angle, recall) you get $\cos(\arcsin(u))=\sqrt{1-u^2}$.

Actually, this integral doesn't have a closed form; are you sure the problem wasn't $\int \sqrt{x} \cos^2 x dx$

Comment: This substitution isn't valid though, with $x\in [0,\pi]$, so we're going to have to break it up into two intervals and be very careful.

Comment: Yes, i am sure it is the integral that i give :(